# A fast way to merge named vectors of different length into a data frame (preserving name information as column name) in R

Tags: r, merge

I have a list L of named vectors. For example, 1st element:

```
> L[[1]]
$event
[1] "EventA"

$time
[1] "1416355303"

$city
[1] "Los Angeles"

$region
[1] "California"

$Locale
[1] "en-GB"
```

when I `unlist` each element of the list the resulting vectors looks like this (for the 1st 3 elements):

```
> unlist(L[[1]])
    event          time          city        region        Locale 
 "EventA"  "1416355303" "Los Angeles"  "California"       "en-GB" 

> unlist(L[[2]])
   event         time       Locale 
"EventB" "1416417567"      "en-GB" 

> unlist(L[[3]])
   event properties.time 
 "EventM"    "1416417569"
```

I have over 0.5 million elements in the list and each one has up to 42 of these feaures/names. I have to merge them into a dataframe taken into account their names and that not all of them have the same number of feaures or names (in the example above, V2 has no information for `region` and `city`). At the moment, what I do is a loop through the whole list:

```
df1 <- merge(stack(unlist(L[[1]])), stack(unlist(L[[2]])),
        by = "ind", all = TRUE)
suppressWarnings(for (i in 3:length(L)){
    df1 <- merge(df1, stack(unlist(L[[i]])), by = "ind", all = TRUE)
})
df1 <- as.data.frame(t(df1))
```

For the example above this returns:

```
                 V1     V2     V3         V4         V5
 ind             city  event Locale     region       time
 values.x Los Angeles EventA  en-GB California 1416355303
 values.y        <NA> EventB  en-GB       <NA> 1416417567
 values          <NA> EventM   <NA>       <NA> 1416417569
```

which is what I want. However, bearing in mind the length of the list and the fact that every time that the command:

```
df1 <- merge(df1, stack(unlist(L[[i]])), by = "ind", all = TRUE)
```

runs, loads the entire data frame (df1), the loop takes a very long time. Therefore, I was wondering if anyone knows a better/faster way to code this. In other words. Given a long list of named vectors with different lengths, is there a fast way to merge them into a data frame as the one described above.

For example, is there a way of doing this using `foreach` and `%dopar%`? In any case, any faster approach is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use `merge`. It seems to me like you should simply `rbind`.

```
L <- list(list(event = "EventA", time = 1416355303, 
               city = "Los Angeles", region = "California",
               Locale = "en-GB"),
          list(event = "EventB", time = 1416417567,
               Locale = "en-GB"),
          list(event = "EventM", time = 1416417569))

library(plyr)
do.call(rbind.fill, lapply(L, as.data.frame))
#   event       time        city     region Locale
#1 EventA 1416355303 Los Angeles California  en-GB
#2 EventB 1416417567        <NA>       <NA>  en-GB
#3 EventM 1416417569        <NA>       <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks. the only problem is that the list in reality has the structure `L[[i]]$event` and then `L[[i]]$properties`. And within properties I do have `L[[i]]$properties$time`, `L[[i]]$properties$city` and so on. Therefore, when I run as.data.frame it returns this `Error in data.frame(time = 1416355303, city = "Los Angeles",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`. I will figure out how to change the structure of the list. Thanks again.

Comment: It's your responsibility to provide a reproducible example. Add the output of `dput(L[1:3])` to your question.

Comment: I know I know, I just though it would be easier and more concise if I don´t explain every detail. I figure out how to do it from your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Curious about the `do.call` here.  It seems `rbind.fill(lapply(L, as.data.frame))` works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

I've heard the `data.table` package is pretty fast.  And `rbindlist` is perfect for this list.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(L, fill=TRUE)
#     event       time        city     region Locale
# 1: EventA 1416355303 Los Angeles California  en-GB
# 2: EventB 1416417567          NA         NA  en-GB
# 3: EventM 1416417569          NA         NA     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a compact solution to consider:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(L), L1 ~ L2, value.var = "value")
#   L1        city  event Locale     region       time
# 1  1 Los Angeles EventA  en-GB California 1416355303
# 2  2        <NA> EventB  en-GB       <NA> 1416417567
# 3  3        <NA> EventM   <NA>       <NA> 1416417569
```

Answer (score 1):

The original post is about merging named vectors. Define the first two given in the example above as vectors:

```
>C1 <- c(event = "EventA", time = 1416355303, 
     city = "Los Angeles", region = "California",
     Locale = "en-GB")
>C2 <- c(event = "EventB", time = 1416417567,
           Locale = "en-GB")
```

If you want to merge them and are OK to give up the extra data in the longer vector vector, then you can index the longer vector by names in the shorter vector

```
>C1 <- C1[names(C2)]
```

Then just use rbind or cbind. Example with rbind

```
>C1_C2 <- rbind(C1,C2)
>C1_C2

   event    time         Locale 
C1 "EventA" "1416355303" "en-GB"
C2 "EventB" "1416417567" "en-GB"
```

You can combine the final two steps but will lose the name of the first vector if you do that