# rbind named vector to matrix with different lengths

Tags: r, matrix, vector, rbind

I am trying to bind together a named vector onto a matrix.  The named vector has a different length as the matrix:

```
> m <- matrix(data = c("1", "2", "3"), 
            nrow = 1, ncol = 3, 
            dimnames = list(c(), 
                            c("column 1", "column 2", "column 3")))

> named_vec <- c("4", "5")
> names(named_vec) <- c("column 1", "column 2")

> rbind(m, named_vec)
```

I get the following:

```
Warning message:
In rbind(m, named_vec) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

This has the undesired effect of repeating the shorter vector.
Also, plyr's rbind.fill function does not work here, since both arguments need to be data frames:

```
> plyr::rbind.fill(data.frame(m), data.frame(named_vec))

Error: All inputs to rbind.fill must be data.frames
```

My desired output is a matrix that fills in missing values with NA's instead of repeating the vector, like this:

```
     column 1 column 2 column 3
[1,] "1"      "2"      "3"     
[2,] "4"      "5"      NA
```

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170805/a-fast-way-to-merge-named-vectors-of-different-length-into-a-data-frame-preserv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a base R solution

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(u<-list(m,named_vec),`length<-`,max(lengths(u))))
```

such that

```
     column 1 column 2 column 3
[1,] "1"      "2"      "3"     
[2,] "4"      "5"      NA
```

Comment: This worked great, and after using microbenchmark I confirmed it was also the fastest out of the answers for my application. Thanks!

Comment: Warning! This solution is giving wrong (!) results if your missing values does not happen to be the last positions. Try the same but name your `names(named_vec) <- c("column 2", "column 3")` and see what happens

Comment: @tjebo yes, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

If it is ok to convert the matrices to dataframe, you can use `bind_rows`.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(data.frame(m), data.frame(t(named_vec)))

#  column.1 column.2 column.3
#1        1        2        3
#2        4        5     <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(as.data.frame(m), as.data.frame(t(named_vec))), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  This gave me the desired result, but I did have to specify `fill = T` first.

Comment: @AlexW  sorry, yes, if the column names are not similar, then yes `fill  = TRUE` is needed