# How to fill in R data.frame with named vectors of different lengths?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to fill in R data.frame (or data.table) using named vectors as rows. The problem is that named vectors to be used as rows usually do not have all the variables. In other words, usually named vector has smaller length than the number of columns. Names of variables in the vectors coincide with column names of the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, 2, 3))
colnames(df) <- c("A", "B", "C")
obs1 <- c(A=2, B=4)
obs2 <- c(A=3, C=10)
```

I want df as follows:

```
> df
  A  B  C
1 2  4 NA
2 3 NA 10
```

So I want to fill in the first two rows with obs1 and obs2 respectively. When I try to do it, I get an error:

```
> df[1,] <- obs1
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, , value = c(A = 2, B = 4)) : 
  replacement has 2 items, need 3
```

I suspect that similar question was already asked, but I could not find it. Does anybody know how to do it using data.frame or data.table?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553460/rbind-named-vector-to-matrix-with-different-lengths/61555104?noredirect=1#comment133680054_61555104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to select the columns as well based on the `names` of 'obs1' and 'obs2'

```
df[1, names(obs1)] <- obs1
df[2, names(obs2)] <- obs2
```

-output

```
> df
  A  B  C
1 2  4 NA
2 3 NA 10
```

---

When we do `df[1,]`, it returns the first row with all the columns i.e. the `length` is 3 where as 'obs1' or 'obs2' have only a length of 2, thus getting the error in length

---

Also, creating a template dataset to fill is not really needed as we can use `bind_rows` which will automatically fill with `NA` for those columns not present

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(obs1, obs2)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     4    NA
2     3    NA    10
```

Answer (score 2):

solution with `data.table`;

```
library(data.table)
obs1 <- data.table(t(obs1))
obs2 <- data.table(t(obs2))
df <- rbindlist(list(obs1,obs2),fill=T)
df
```

**output;**

```
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     4    NA
2     3    NA    10
```